# Excel Conditional Formatting: Using a worksheet-scoped named range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, named-ranges

Recently I had to change previously Workbook-scoped named ranges to Worksheet-scope. These were used in conditional formatting rules. Now I appear to be unable to continue using them by adding the sheets name to the reference:

Sheet1 contains data and uses conditional formatting. Suppose Sheet2 contains a named range "ConstantX" referring to Sheet2:A1. This Name is scoped to Sheet2.

When trying to set up a CF in Sheet1 as e.g. `=Q3 > Sheet2!ConstantX` I receive the error message "This type of reference cannot be used in a Conditional Formatting formula".

It is however happy if I were to replace Sheet2!ConstantX with Sheet2!A1, but this is not an acceptable workaround.
Changing the scope back to workbook is equally bad unfortunately, since that particular sheet is copied and pasted when I run my automated updates, destroying workbook-scope references.

Is there a solution to be using worksheet-scoped named ranges in another worksheet's conditional formatting rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it out quickly, it looks like you might be able to use INDIRECT. So your conditional formatting formula would look like:

```
=Q3 > INDIRECT("Sheet2!ConstantX")
```

I hope that works

Comment: +1. Very interesting behaviour. Not sure I've come across a case where an indirect reference works though the equivalent direct reference does not.

Comment: Yes it seems a bit odd. Playing around with it a bit more. It appears like you can use a worksheet-scoped name on its own so just `Q3 > ConstantX`. The formatting is applied based on the value of the worksheet-scoped name even if a workbook-scoped name with the same name but different value exists

Comment: That does work, and I find it equally intriguing. I can't see the reasoning behind it but maybe someone can... Global names work without any problems, worksheet scoped ones only with this workaround.

Comment: `Q3 > ConstantX` does not work for me. Trying it as a cell value results in #?Name error. Formatting is not applied - but it would have surprised me even more if it did.

Comment: What does work however is adding a locally scoped name (Sheet1!ConstantX) that refers to = Sheet2!ConstantX. It's funny...
But I'll have to go with the indirect approach since deleting and re-adding Sheet2 would destroy those local reference copies as well as on the workbook scope. So Indirect it is - it's only used for a couple of constants anyway so the overhead shouldn't be significant to worry about for me. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @ExternalUse Curiouser and curiouser!

Comment: @ExternalUse Conditional Formatting is already "supervolatile", so the use of volatile functions therein is perhaps a moot point.